# Clickhouse: Is it possible to specify OFFSET n in SQL query?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I want to skip 1M records in the output. How can I do it?

Comment: Clickhouse does seem to supports its own version of `LIMIT` ([see here](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/111)), but alas, I don't see anything for `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try `LIMIT 1000000,1`
and see documentation https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/select/#limit-clause

and maybe you need side autoincrement atomic counter (i.e. via REDIS INCR command) and insert this counter with your data 
and use WHERE id BETWEEN 1000000 AND 1000001